# WordPress Plugin settings page(options_page) redirecting to DB Upgrade page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been building a plugin for WordPress for a client, however I seem to be having a strange problem. I have added an options page but it's not working correctly.

When I go to the Wordpress menu I can see my options page. It has the correct options page `options-general.php?page=Beacon_Registation_WP`, however when I click on the menu item that page redirects me to `upgrade.php?_wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Foptions-general.php%3Fpage%3DBeacon_Registation_WP`

Am unsure why this is happening.

The code im using as the entry point for the plugin:

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: ** OMITED **
* Plugin URI: ** OMITED **
* Description: This plugin enabled the wordpress site to register new users to the beaconapp 
* Version: 1.0
* Author: Martin Barker - ** OMITED **
* Author URI: ** OMITED **
* License: Propriatry Software (do not distribute)
*/

class BeaconRegistation
{
    // handler for registing the wp-admin menu
    public function addMenuItem()
    {
        add_options_page( 'Configure Server', 'BeaconApp Registation', 'manage_options', 'Beacon_Registation_WP', array($this, "wp_admin") );
    }

    // display the wp_admin page for this plugin
    public function wp_admin()
    {
        ob_start();
        if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
            wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
        }
        $this->sdr = get_option("sdr", "martindev.** OMITED **");
        if($_POST['sdr'] !== $this->sdr){
            update_option("sdr", $_POST['sdr']);
            $this->sdr = get_option("sdr", "martindev.** OMITED **");
        }
        // include the view for switch environment
        include("admin.php");
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    // displays the shortcode 'ba_business_form'
    public function showBusinessForm($atts, $content = "")
    {
        ob_start();
        if($_POST['form_mode'] == "business"){
            // form has been posted
        }else{
            include("business.html");
        }

        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    // displays the short code 'ba_agency_form'
    public function showAgencyForm($atts, $content = "")
    {
        ob_start();
        if($_POST['form_mode'] == "agency"){
            // form has been posted
        }else{
            include("agency.html");
        }

        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    public function init()
    {
        // add the admin menu call
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array($this, "addMenuItem"));

        // add the short code for the business form
        add_shortcode("ba_business_form", array($this, "showBusinessForm"));

        // add the short code for the agency form
        add_shortcode("ba_agency_form", array($this, "showAgencyForm"));
    }
}

(new BeaconRegistation())->init();
```

Just to confirm the 2 shortcodes are working correctly so the only problem is the options_page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some hacking of the Wordpress admin panel, we managed to dig this down to the `include("admin.php")` I'm unsure how but WordPress seems to interfere and prevent this process from working.

so the `include` relative paths seem to work as it does with the `include("business.html");` and `include("agency.html");` however the "admin.php" one just seems to not occur it's like another admin.php get's included unsure how or why this happens.

so to fix i resolved the absolute path and included via that `include(realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."/admin.php");`

Comment: You probably included the standard admin.php. It has a redirect like yours in [line 50](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/admin.php#L50). The manual for [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) states that it'll check the include_path first, and then the dir of the calling file and cwd. That explains that business and agency worked as expected.